# question mark characters and page refresh

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am running into an issue where I have question marks showing on one page while others the characters are showing up fine.  both of the pages share the same declaration at the top:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

However only one of them is able to consistently display Chinese characters.  Sometimes when I refresh the browser, then the characters show up.  I don't understand why two pages almost exactly the same would exhibit this type of behavior, has anyone seen this before ?

Edit: Adding the fact that I also specified in the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I'm starting to think it could be a caching issue in the browser, since when i inspect the element, it's using an older version of the .jsp file than the most current one...

Comment: oops looks like that wasn't the case, it's very strange since it was showing the correct characters until i restarted the server once and now it's only showing question marks

Comment: Replacing chinese characters with their respective ASCII codes should do the job!Can you give it a try?Also,did you inspect rendered jsp for both your cases?

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883467/special-characters-turned-into-question-mark-after-duplication-of-the-same-page